# How to turn off only speaker audio (not system audio) for a specific Chrome website (Windows 11)?

Tags: google-chrome, audio, windows-11, speakers

I need to turn off only speaker audio (not system audio) for a specific Chrome website. I tried with the Volume Master Chrome extension but that turns off both speaker audio and system audio. Right click on the Chrome tab and "mute site" for some reason is not working on my laptop, but I feel it might mute both speaker audio and system audio.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an extension for that. Try to mute a specific website in:

Chrome settings -> Privacy and security from the left menu -> Site settings -> Additional content settings at the end of the page -> Sound -> Add the domain of the website to the mute list.

Try to test muting other apps, right click the sound icon on the task bar then select Open Volume Mixer. If muting other apps individually doesn't work then it's a Windows issue.

If right click mute on the tab doesn't work then probably there is an issue with your Chrome. Check for an update in the Chrome help menu, or you can wait for the next Chrome update, if it's a widespread issue hopefully it will be fixed.

You can also uninstall/reinstall chrome. Make sure to backup your logins/bookmarks/extensions/...etc before uninstalling just in case something goes wrong. You can also make a copy of the Chrome settings folder, but keep in mind that restoring doesn't always work from that folder:
C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\

After reinstalling, you will need to add all your extensions again manually, and you will probably be logged out of all your accounts on all websites if they are not stored in your Google Chrome Account.